# Can't hide post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to exclude a category from homepage. I tried the below code, it's working for my site in local server but after I moved the code to production server it won't work at all.

```
function exclude_category($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '-505' );
    }
return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

I even tried to install 'wp-hide-post' plugin, yet, it's not working.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the category ID the same on both servers?

Comment: bet your databases are different and ID's don't match

Comment: the ID is the same . And yeah, I changed the ID to reflect the ID on the server.